# Why member is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

```
    client.on('raw', (e) => {
    if (e.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD' && e.d.message_id === '813150433651851265' && e.d.emoji.name === "✅" )
    {
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(e.d.guild_id)
        const member = guild.members.cache.find(user => user.id === e.d.user_id)
        console.log(member)
        const role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "812809799233699871")
        if (!member.roles.find(role => role.id === "812809799233699871")) member.roles.add(role)
        else return
    }
})
```

I'm trying to make a reaction role. But member is undefined? Someone know why?

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(guild.members.cache)`?

Comment: It is `undefined` because there is no element in `guild.members.cache` who's `id` property matches `e.d.user_id`.

Comment: then how to define member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to first emit the messageReactionAdd event, and then run a messageReactionAdd event and configure using that, since it easier than using the raw event, Here's how to emit messageReactionAdd event,

```
client.on('raw', (packet) => {
if(!['MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD'].includes(packet.t)) return undefined;

let channel = client.channels.cache.get(packet.d.channel_id);
if(channel.messages.cache.has(packet.d.message_id)) return undefined;

channel.messages.fetch(packet.d.message_id).then(message => {
    const emoji = packet.d.emoji.id ? `${packet.d.emoji.name}:${packet.d.emoji.id}` : packet.d.emoji.name;
    const reaction = message.reactions.cache.get(emoji);
    if (reaction) reaction.users.cache.set(packet.d.user_id, client.users.cache.get(packet.d.user_id));

    if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
        client.emit('messageReactionAdd', reaction, client.users.cache.get(packet.d.user_id));
    }
})
```

})

Now you can using the messageReactionAdd event to for you reaction role,

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  //Do your thing here.
})
```

Hope this helps,